# How to add a view an centered between and under two other views by constraint programmatically? Swift

Tags: swift, constraints

1. How can I add `bestChoiceImage` in center of the distance under `ratingLabel` and `rateButton`?
2. Why, when I'm using `print(anysubview.center.x)` is it = 0.0, but in Simulator everything staying in its place?

/activate inside viewWillappear

```
    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.width

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        reebokClassic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: viewHeight/12),
        reebokClassic.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),

        modelName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reebokClassic.bottomAnchor, constant: viewHeight/100),
        modelName.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),

        sneakersImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: modelName.bottomAnchor, constant: viewHeight/40),
        sneakersImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        sneakersImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth * 0.8),
        sneakersImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth * 0.8),

        segmentedController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth),
        segmentedController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sneakersImage.bottomAnchor, constant: viewHeight/80),
        segmentedController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        segmentedController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight/23),

        lastTimeWeared.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedController.bottomAnchor, constant: viewHeight/40),
        lastTimeWeared.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: viewHeight/100),
        lastTimeWeared.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/3),

        ratingLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedController.bottomAnchor, constant: viewHeight/40),
        ratingLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -viewHeight/50),
        ratingLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/3),

        slipOnButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -viewHeight/20),
        slipOnButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -viewWidth/20),
        slipOnButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/5),
        slipOnButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight/20),

        rateButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -viewHeight/20),
        rateButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: viewWidth/20),
        rateButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/5),
        rateButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight/20),

        bestChoiceImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/3),
        bestChoiceImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewWidth/3),
        bestChoiceImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        bestChoiceImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant:
            -(**rateButton.center.y - ratingLabel.center.y - bestChoiceImage.frame.height/2**))
    ])
```

Comment: use stackview instead

Comment: Write me a message in telegram to @mikeisaev  if you interested to use UIKitPlus https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus I could help you with all the constraints questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put ratingLabel and rateButton in a container view (e.g. a stack view) and constraints between bestChoiceImage and that container view.
2. You probably print it before the autolayout engine actually did its work. Try printing it in viewDidAppear for example.